# Is it possible to use SYB to transform the type?

Tags: haskell, scrap-your-boilerplate

I want to write a `rename` function to replace `String` names (which represent hierarchical identifiers) in my `AST` with `GUID` names (integers) from a symbol table carried as hidden state in a `Renamer` monad.

I have an `AST a` type that is parameterized over the type of name.  Names in the leaves of the AST are of type `Name a`:

```
data Name a = Name a
```

Which makes it easy to target them with a SYB transformer.

The parser is typed (ignoring the possibility of error for brevity):

```
parse :: String -> AST String
```

and I want the `rename` function to be typed:

```
rename :: AST String -> Renamer (AST GUID)
```

Is it possible to use SYB to transform all `Name String`'s into `Name GUID`'s with a transformer:

```
resolveName :: Name String -> Renamer (Name GUID)
```

and all other values from `c String` to `c GUID` by transforming their children, and pasting them back together with the same constructor, albeit with a different type parameter?

The `everywhereM` function is close to what I want, but it can only transform `c a -> m (c a)` and not `c a -> m (c b)`.

My fallback solution (other than writing the boiler-plate by hand) is to remove the type parameter from `AST`, and define `Name` like this:

```
data Name = StrName String
          | GuidName GUID
```

so that the rename would be typed:

```
rename :: AST -> Renamer AST
```

making it work with `everywhereM`.  However, this would leave the possibility that an `AST` could still hold `StrName`'s after being renamed.  I wanted to use the type system to formally capture the fact that a renamed `AST` can only hold `GUID` names.

Comment: If all your types have a single parameter, you can probably make them instances of Functor, Foldable and Traversable, then use the mapM operation of Traversable. In general changing the type of syntax trees is problematic - parametrizing a syntax tree is not very flexible (Haskell only has classes for the arity 1 Functor case), and with no parameters you have the "nanopass" problem - Neil Brown had a paper about this at the Haskell Workshop a couple of years ago.

Comment: Thanks!  I found the [paper](http://offog.org/publications/fita200811-generics.pdf).  It looks very interesting.

Comment: Could you please point me to the synthesize examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution (perhaps less efficient than you were hoping for) would be to make your AST an instance of `Functor`, `Data` and `Typeable` (GHC 7 can probably derive all of these for you) then do:

```
import Data.Generics.Uniplate.Data(universeBi) -- from the uniplate package
import qualified Data.Map as Map

rename :: AST String -> Renamer (AST GUID)
rename x = do
    let names = nub $ universeBi x :: [Name String]
    guids <- mapM resolveName names
    let mp = Map.fromList $ zip names guids
    return $ fmap (mp Map.!) x
```

Two points:

1. I'm assuming it's easy to eliminate the `Name` bit from `resolveName`, but I suspect it is.
2. You can switch `universeBi` for something equivalent in SYB, but I find it much easier to understand the Uniplate versions.